# Knaster Tarski theorem, example needed

Tags: set-theory, fixed-point-theorems, lattice-theory

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Tarski_theorem

Let $L$ be a complete lattice and let $f : L \to L$ be an order-preserving function. Then the set of fixed points of $f$ in $L$ is also a complete lattice.

Can  someone think of a non-trivial example for which the theorem applies ?

Comment: An increasing function $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$? 

Answer (score 17):

You can use this to prove the [Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem) theorem, which asserts that whenever $A$ injects into $B$ and $B$ injects into $A$, then they are bijective. Namely, suppose that $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$ are both injective functions. If there were a set $X\subset A$ such that $A-X=g[B-f[X]]$, then the function $h=(f\upharpoonright X)\cup (g^{-1}\upharpoonright A-X)$ is a bijection between $A$ and $B$. Such a set $X$ exists by the Knaster-Tarski theorem, since the powerset $P(A)$ is a complete lattice under inclusion and the function $\varphi(X)=A-g[B-f[X]]$ is $\subset$-preserving, since $$X\subset Y\implies f[X]\subset f[Y]\implies B-f[X]\supset B-f[Y]$$ $$\implies A-g[B-f[X]]\subset A-g[B-f[Y]]\implies \varphi(X)\subset\varphi(Y).$$
A fixed point $X=\varphi(x)$ means $A-X=g[B-f[X]]$.

Comment: That's a very slick proof of the CSB Theorem! Thanks Joel.

Comment: Sure. **Elegant!** After all, it was **Stefan Banach** himself.

Answer (score 8):

A useful application of Tarski's fixed point theorem is that every supermodular game (mostly games with strategic complementarities) has a smallest and a largest pure strategy Nash equilibrium. For surveys of supermodular games, see [here](http://www.stanford.edu/~jdlevin/Econ%2520286/Supermodular%2520Games.pdf), [here](http://www.iese.edu/research/pdfs/OP-07-18-E.pdf), or [here](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~kevinlb/teaching/cs532a%2520-%25202006-7/projects/ashiquepqper.pdf). The literature is huge. By a slight modification of the theorem, one can actually [show](http://ideas.repec.org/a/eee/gamebe/v7y1994i2p295-300.html) that the set of pure strategy Nash equilibria forms a complete lattice in itself.

Answer (score 3):

In computer science, it is used in the field of denotational semantics and abstract interpretation, where the existence of fixed points can be exploited to guarantee well-defined semantics for a recursive algorithm, see [this](http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/~forressa/academic/701-talk.pdf) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

In [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/203725/an-unfair-marriage-lemma/203750#203750) graph-theoretical post you find a very nice application of Knaster-Tarski to a generalization of [Hall's Marriage Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

There are applications to finding invariant sets of [iterated function systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function_system) (a notion related to fractals). See this [survey](http://dx.doi.org/10.2478/s11533-012-0109-4) by K. Leśniak.

Answer (score 1):

It can be used to give a quick [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3026040/76258) for this [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3016149/given-a-book-with-100-pages-and-a-100-lemmas-prove-that-there-is-some-lemma/):

> A book consists of 100 pages and contains 100 lemmas and some images.
>   Each lemma is at most one page long and can't be split into two pages
>   (it has to fit in one page). The lemmas are numbered from 1 to 100 and
>   are written in ascending order. Prove that there must be at least one
>   lemma written on a page with the same number as the lemma's number.