# An unfair marriage lemma

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, matching-theory

I am looking for a citeable reference to the following generalization of Hall's Marriage Theorem:

- Given a bipartite graph of boys and girls. In addition to gender difference, they are divided into 1st and 2nd class citizens. Suppose that Hall's condition is satisfied for 1st class citizens. That is, for every set $M\subset\{\text{1st class boys}\}$ there are at least $|M|$ girls (from both classes) adjacent to $M$. And similarly for every $W\subset\{\text{1st class girls}\}$ there are at least $|W|$ boys adjacent to $W$. Then there exists a matching covering all 1st class citizens.

I need this fact as a lemma in a paper on geometric analysis. The proof is more or less straightforward but it occupies some space when written down. And I suspect that the fact may be well-known to specialists. Is this indeed the case and what are relevant references?

Comment: It's a really nice theorem and you should write down your proof. Should it go into your paper on geometric analysis? I don't know, but I wouldn't see a reason why not.

Comment: @darij: Yes, of course we will prove it in the paper if there is no reference. It just looks too natural to be unknown.

Comment: Notice that your lemma generalizes Hall's theorem (just declare all boys to be 1st class and all girls to be 2nd class).

Comment: Great question (and answer!). Have you already uploaded your article? I would be interested in seeing it!

Comment: @Dominic van der Zypen: Yes we have just finished it. It is on http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.06781

Comment: Other discussions on this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1268005/extending-matchings-in-a-bipartite-graph and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1188829/union-of-two-matching-sets-being-a-matching?rq=1

Comment: This question is unfair and politically incorrect! I like it very much nevertheless!

Comment: At least it is not gender-biased :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In this answer I sketch an easy proof of your lemma and then give some references.

The easy proof uses Knaster's fixed point theorem:

THEOREM. Let $S$ be any set (finite or infinite) and let $\varphi:\mathcal P(S)\to\mathcal P(S)$ be an order-preserving map, i.e., $X\subseteq Y\implies\varphi(X)\subseteq\varphi(Y).$ Then $\varphi$ has a fixed point.

PROOF. Let $X_0=\bigcup\{X\in\mathcal P(S):X\subseteq\varphi(X)\}.$ It is easy to see that $\varphi(X_0)=X_0.$

(Knaster's fixed point theorem was set as a [Putnam Problem in 1957](https://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol5712.html). The generalization to complete lattices is called the [Knaster-Tarski Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Tarski_theorem).)

Now let $B_1,B_2,G_1,G_2$ be the set of all first-class boys, second-class boys, first-class girls, and second-class girls, respectively; $B=B_1\cup B_2,\ G=G_1\cup G_2,\ B_1\cap B_2=G_1\cap G_2=\emptyset.$ By Hall's theorem there are matchings $f:B_1\to G$ and $g:G_1\to B.$ Define an order-preserving map $\varphi:\mathcal P(B_1)\to\mathcal P(B_1)$ by setting, for $X\subseteq B_1,$
$$\varphi(X)=B_1\setminus g[G_1\setminus f[X]].$$
By Knaster's fixed point theorem we have $\varphi(X_0)=X_0$ for some $X_0\subseteq B_1$. Now we can match the boys in $X_0$ with the girls in $f[X_0]$ and the girls in $G_1\setminus f[X_0]$ with the boys in $g[G_1\setminus f[X_0]].$

Here are some references related to your lemma:

L. Mirsky, *Transversal Theory*, Academic Press, New York and London, 1971.

L. Mirsky and Hazel Perfect, Systems of representatives, J. Math. Analysis Appl. 15 (1966), 520-568.

O. Ore, *Theory of Graphs*, Amer. Math. Soc. Colloquium Publications No. 38, Providence, 1962 [Theorem 7.4.1].

Here is how your lemma is stated on p. 36 of Mirsky's book:

> THEOREM 2.3.1. *Let $(X,\Delta,Y)$ be a deltoid and let $X',Y'$ be admissible subsets of $X,Y$ respectively. Then there exist linked sets $X_0,Y_0$ such that $X'\subseteq X_0\subseteq X,\ Y'\subseteq Y_0\subseteq Y.$*

The jargon is defined on pp. 33-34. Namely, a *deltoid* $(X,\Delta,Y)$ is a bipartite graph with partite sets $X,Y$ and edge set $\Delta$; a set $X'\subseteq X$ is *admissible* if there is an injective matching of $X'$ to $Y$; a set $Y'\subseteq Y$ is *admissible* if there is an injective matching of $Y'$ to $X$; two sets $X_0\subseteq X,Y_0\subseteq Y$ are *linked* if there is a bijective matching of $X_0$ to $Y_0.$

**P.S.** Sergei Ivanov has commented that the result, as stated in the question, can be traced back to Dulmage & Mendelsohn, Some generalizations of the problem of distinct representatives, Canad. J. Math. 10 (1958) 230–241, Theorem 1.

Comment: Very nice proof! I like how it weaponizes one of the most trivial facts in mathematics.

Comment: Thanks! I tracked it from Mirski & Perfect's paper down to Dulmage & Mendelsohn, Coverings of bipartite graphs, Canad. J. Math. 10 (1958) 517-534, Theorem 1. And there (unlike the other sources) it is exactly it, not something that one has to combine with Hall's Theorem.

Comment: @bof: I think we are going to thank you in acknowledgements. Do you prefer to be mentioned as an anonym or by some real name?

Comment: The Dulmage/Mendelsohn reference is wrong; this is certainly not Theorem 1 in that paper.

Comment: Oops, yes, wrong paper. It is Theorem 1 in the paper "Some Generalizations of the Problem of Distinct Representatives" same authors, same volume, pages 230-241. https://doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1958-027-8 .

Comment: @SergeiIvanov: Ah, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

I have not seen it stated anywhere, but I would call it a corollary of Hall. It is in fact very natural, so it would not surprise me if it has been stated before.

Simplest proof I can come up with using Hall:

Hall gives you a matching from the first class boys into the girls, and a matching from the first class girls into the boys, record all these edges with this direction to get a directed graph, which consists of directed paths and even cycles. Delete every other edge in every cycle, and delete the second, fourth, etc. edge of every path. Note that the last vertex in every path is 2nd class, so this yields a matching covering all first class vertices.

Comment: Yes, we have the very same argument. It would be 5 lines long if we were aiming at combinatorialists. But it took more than a page to make the text consumable by analysts.

Comment: Why do you assume that analysts can't understand the five-line version?

Comment: @David: Because we tested it on live analysts. It turns out that the very *language* of graph theory is not as widely understood as one might hope.